Recognizing small images on screenshot by specific keyword
I need consultation, idea from experienced developers.
I am using tesseract OCR to recognize text on some screenshots from a web page but I can extract just text. My problem is that, if I find that text is part of some image like product or it is on the product, I would like to find a solution to detect small images from that big web page screenshot.
For example:
on uploaded screenshot I am searching for a keyword "history" and I want to crop every piece of page where I find text "history". But, also If word "history" is part of some image like books in first row, I would like to somehow crop the image box in full, not just keyword.
Is there a solution for this kind of task? What library would be best to use? Open-CV,Google Cloud Vision ...
I am just searching for ideas so I can start. I expect advice how to approach this task.


those are web pages. use the source. don't take a picture. learn about "web scraping".

Thanks Christoph, I had that on my mind also, but I am provided with just screenshots, so I have to work with what I have. Thank you anyway :)
